# Angular 7 returning Observable not working

Tags: angular, observable, angular7

I m trying to make a request and get the response as Observable but somehow its not working. But i can see that i get response in Network. Any ideas ?

```
public getTopRecepies(tag, limit, language): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(() => {
      const params: SlotGamesRequestParams = {
        lang: language,
        limit: limit,
        page: 1,
        tag: tag
      };
      this.recepieRequest
        .setQueryParams(params)
        .makeRequest();
    });
  }
```

And trying to subscribe in the component like this

```
private getRecepies(tag, limit): void {
   
    let language = this.service.getLanguage();
    this.recepieService.getTopRecepies(tag, limit, language).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to push anything to the new observable. It won't emit unless something is pushed to it.

Instead if the `makeRequest()` already returns an observable, you could return it directly. You don't need to create a new observable.

Try the following

```js
public getTopRecepies(tag, limit, language): Observable<any> {
  const params: SlotGamesRequestParams = {
    lang: language,
    limit: limit,
    page: 1,
    tag: tag
  };
  return this.recepieRequest
    .setQueryParams(params)
    .makeRequest();
}
```

Comment: No it doesnt return Observable

Comment: @TolgaTamer: What does it return? There are other functions that you can use to convert it to an observable. But if it's synchronous and doesn't return an observable, _why_ do you want to convert it to an observable and make it asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't push any values inside the observable.

See [RXJS - Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) for more info.

An example here: [Stackblitz - Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmetm9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)